# Dataframe compare two elements with function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following boolean function which compares two values, with a few fallbacks:

```
def __score_bool(a, b,
        default_element_value_if_null=None,
        default_score_if_any_element_is_null=None):
    if (default_element_value_if_null is not None):
        if (a is None): a = default_element_value_if_null
        if (b is None): b = default_element_value_if_null
    if a == b:
         return 1
    if (a is None or b is None) and default_score_if_any_element_is_null:
        return default_score_if_any_element_is_null
    else:
        return 0
```

Now, I'd like to add an additional field to a data frame that compares one field to a static value. For example:

```
df['score_name'] = df.apply(__score_bool, 'name', 'thomas')
```

In the above, I'd like to compare the 'name' in each row to the value 'thomas'. An example would be:

To start:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'eric'}, {'name': 'thomas'}])
>>> df
     name
0    eric
1  thomas
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
name     score_name
'eric'    0
'thomas'  1
```

How would I do this?

---

**Update**:

The current approach I have is:

```
df['score_name'] = df.apply(lambda row: __score_bool(row['name'], 'thomas'), axis=1)
```

But this seems very crude having to first pass it to a lambda function (to extract the row) and then having to pass it to another function to extract the column value. Is there a more direct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
df['score_name'] = df['name'].apply(__score_bool, b='thomas')
```

Comment: oh of course, just applying it to the field rather than the data frame. Thanks for the help!